# UIImagePickerController shows last picture taken instead of camera input

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a strange behaviour within my app.
For taking pictures i'm using the following pretty standard code for displaying the UIImagePickerController:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works perfectly fine the first time I tap the button which calls this action. The strange behaviour starts when I tap that button again. The UIImagePickerController starts again BUT it doesnt show the input from the camera anymore. It shows the last picture I've taken.

More Details of this state:

- Tapping on the image shows the yellow square of the auto focus. (which it actually uses to focus the camera correctly)
- When I tap on the ImageCapture button -> the **correct** image is taken and presented on the screen.
- If I take a picture and press 'Retake' the regular camera image is presented as input.

More weirdness: It has nothing to do with the iPad I'm using. Creating a new example app which only has button which calls the code from above everything works perfectly fine.

I assume it has something to do with the configuration of the app. Therefore I checked everything but could not find any differences which may cause this issue.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Update: 
I do implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in order to dismiss the UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did find the issue: It was a category on UIViewController I used somewhere else in the project. As soon as I compiled it with my project, the UIImagePickerController acted weird. So I think I somehow managed to use a method name which is also used internally by UIImagePickerController. It still confuses me a little since the category wasn't used on the UIImagePickerController at all.

Answer (score 0):

In reading the Apple documentation on UIImagePickerController [doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070) it states that "When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image or movie, or cancels the operation, **dismiss the image picker using your delegate object**. For newly-captured media, your delegate can then save it to the Camera Roll on the device. For previously-saved media, your delegate can then use the  image data according to the purpose of your app." Maybe you need to implement the UIImagePickerContriollerDelegate protocol methods and properly dismiss the existing UIImagePickerController object. See [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But of course I already do implement the delegate. Otherwise I could not dismiss the ImagePickerController :)

Comment: doh...sorry. Given that you can create an example project that just has the camera code and it works fine, it might be worth it to post the code for the entire object that uses your camera code. It might be that something else going on in your object is affecting it.